# how to store data in Java with key name and its value?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I have a situation where i want to store data in an object with a key and its value. The key name is the same, but the value is changed. i tried to use hash Map but it also does not support this. it overwrites all values and gives me only the recent value in pair.

my question is: are there any classes or methods that can help me sort out this problem?

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-07-2000/jw-0707-java101.html

Comment: You want to store multiple values tied to a single key? That's certainly possible. How do you distinguish which one is the correct value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What data structure to use**

If the requirement is to store multiple values for a single key, then using a [multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) would be a good option.

One implementation of such a multimap is the [`Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from the [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library.

The `Multimap` interface in Guava has several implementations depending on the requirements for the multiplicity and ordering of the keys and values.

**Choosing an implementation**

A simple implementation is the [`HashMultimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html), where the values mapped by a key will not allow duplicates, and the ordering of the keys are not determinant.

The [`ArrayListMultimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) preserves the order of the values mapped to a key, in the order at which they were mapped to the key.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to keep track of multiple values, you could possibly use a `List` value in the Map.  You could use the assumption that the last value in the List is the most recent value, if that meets your requirements.

Creating such a map would be done like this (though your key and value types don't have to be Strings, they could be whatever classes you're using):

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Then to get the latest value for a given key, you'd need to get the last element of the corresponding list:

```
List<String> list = map.get(key);
String value = null;
if (list != null) {
   value = list.get(list.size() - 1);
}
```

To add a value to the Map, you'd need to add logic to create a new list if no value exists for a new key, otherwise add the new value to the end of the list:

```
if (map.get(key) == null) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(value);
    map.put(key, list);
}
else {
    map.get(key).add(value);
}
```

Comment: If it makes sense to do so, consider subclassing HashMap in order to encapsulate this logic in a class. Provide a simple interface such as `put`, `getLast`, `getAll`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, or possibly just include a Multimap implementation as some of the other posts suggest.  Those slipped my mind, I've used one in the past and it's pretty handy.

Comment: could you provide with a an example in Core JAVA for the above question.This is really interesting and if you could render your help with an example.it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Java's standard collections don't include a class for so-called "multimaps", but several other collection libraries offer this feature. Eg:

- [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) from Apache Commons
- [Multimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from google-collections